# Last occurrence of an element in a very large sorted array

Tags: python, binary-search

> You are given a sorted array that is infinitely large (or with a very large unknown size). You have to write a code that will print the last occurrence of an element.
>
> ###### Input
>
> The first line of the input contains space separated integers representing the elements of the sorted array.
> The second line of the input represents the target element to be found.
>
> ###### Constraints
>
> The array might have duplicate elements i.e the elements are not in strictly increasing fashion.
>
> ###### Output
>
> Print the last occurrence of the target element, otherwise print -1.
>
> ###### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1 2 7 7 14 19 23
> 7
> ```
>
> ###### Sample Output
>
> 3

I'm not able to handle elements that are present at the last index.

```
def binarySearch(target,arr,start,end):
    mid = (start+end)//2
    if start>end:
        return -1
    elif arr[mid] == target:
        if arr[mid] == arr[-1]:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid+1] != target:
            return mid
        else:
            return mid+1
    elif arr[mid] > target:
        return binarySearch(target,arr,start,mid-1)
    elif arr[mid] < target:
        return binarySearch(target,arr,mid+1,end)

def finiteRange(target,arr,start,end):
    while arr[end]<target:
        start = end
        end *= 2

    return binarySearch(target,arr,start,end)

arr = list(map(int,input().split()))
target = int(input())

result = finiteRange(target,arr,0,1)
print(result)
```

Comment: An array cannot be "infinitely large". And if we would assume infinite memory, there is no algorithm that can find the last occurrence in finite time. The "or" part in parentheses describes a *finitely* large array. I suppose we should indeed assume it is always finite.

Comment: *"Print the last occurrence of the target element"*: I suppose this means printing the *index* of the last occurrence?

Comment: Why do you pass 1 as argument for `end`? Why not just `len(arr)-1`?

Comment: As you are *reading* the input values from standard input, why not just stop reading from the input when you encounter a value that is greater than the target and immediately return the number of values you had already read? No need for a list, no need for binary search... I'm lost why all this complexity is needed.

Comment: Because we have to follow infinite series binary search algorith. We can not use len(array) because we have to maintain its time complexity

Comment: Checkout binarysearch solution in [Find first and last positions of an element in a sorted array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-and-last-positions-of-an-element-in-a-sorted-array/)

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `len`, then why are you allowed to use `arr[-1]`. That looks like "cheating".

Comment: @GangadharYadav Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues:

- In `finiteRange` there is no check that `end` is a valid index, i.e. `arr[end]` could throw an exception. Check for instance with the input [1, 2, 3, 7] and target 7. As you indicate that you are not allowed to use `len`, then you should catch the error and still call `binarySearch`
- In `finiteRange` the loop condition has `arr[end] < target`, which also means that if these two are equal, the loop exits, but then you might miss out on the fact that `arr[end+1]` might also be equal to the target, and the call to `binarySearch` will miss it.
- Not a problem, but as `finiteRange` is only called once, it shouldn't get `start` and `end` as arguments. Instead these can be initialised in the function itself.
- If in `binarySearch` you find the target at index `mid`, and see that the target is also found at the end of the list, you still return `mid`, while `mid` might not be the index of the last element in the list. Moreover, if you are not allowed to use `len`, then I would assume that `arr[-1]` is not allowed either. Even more, this *last* entry might have an index that is much greater than `end`, yet your binary search is supposed to only consider the range `start`-`end`.
- When you find that both at index `mid` and `mid+1` the value is the target value, you do `return mid+1` without checking whether maybe that target value is also present at index `mid+2`, ...etc.

The idea is that you also narrow the window from the left side when you find that the left-side value is equal to the target: the binary search should continue. Only when the window becomes empty, you should consider it a base case and return. In that case the `end` index is guaranteed to be what we need if the target value is present in the list. If it is not present in the list, it is for the *caller* (i.e. `finiteRange`) to detect that and return -1 instead.

Here is the corrected code:

```
def binarySearch(target, arr, start, end):
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if start > end:
        return end
    try:  # Trap the error when `mid` is out of range
        if arr[mid] > target:
            return binarySearch(target, arr, start, mid-1)
        else: # Narrow the search also when the target is found
            return binarySearch(target, arr, mid+1, end)
    except IndexError:  # If `mid` is out of range, we go "left"
        return binarySearch(target, arr, start, mid-1)

def finiteRange(target, arr):
    start = 0  # start/end don't need to be parameters
    end = 1
    try:  # Trap the error when accessing an out of range index
        while arr[end] <= target:  # Continue when equal too
            start = end
            end *= 2
    except IndexError:
        pass  # In this case we stop moving the range
    # Use recursion to find the last index of the greatest value
    #  that is not greater than the target
    i = binarySearch(target, arr, 0, end - 1)
    try:
        # Return that index if that greatest value happens to be the target
        return i if arr[i] == target else -1
    except IndexError: # This happens when the list is empty
        return -1
```

Example call:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13]
target = 13
result = finiteRange(target, arr)  # Don't pass 0 and 1 as arguments
print(result)
```

Comment: Binary search is so easy to get wrong that I'd find it helpful to state the precise meaning of the `start`/`end` parameters, i.e., the invariant of the binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modifications (in comments) to your code to find the last occurrence work fine. Try this out.

```
import random


def binarySearch(target,arr,start,end):
    mid = (start+end)//2
    check_value = arr[mid]
    if start>end:
        return -1
    elif check_value == target:
        if arr[mid] == arr[-1] or arr[mid+1] != target:  # check if last occurrence
            return mid
        else:
            return binarySearch(target, arr, mid+1, end)  # recursive call to find last occurrence
    elif check_value > target:
        return binarySearch(target,arr,start,mid-1)
    elif check_value < target:
        return binarySearch(target,arr,mid+1,end)


def finiteRange(target,arr,start,end):
    check_val = arr[start]
    while check_val <= target:  # changed < to <= since we're searching for last occurrence
        start = end
        end *= 2
        try:
            check_val = arr[end]
        except IndexError:
            return -1
    return binarySearch(target,arr,start,end)


# original example produces correct output
arr = list(map(int,input().split()))
target = int(input())
result = finiteRange(target,arr,0,1)
print(result)
# 1 2 7 7 14 19 23
# 7
# 3

# checking with a larger array
target = 50
arr = sorted([random.randint(25, 100) for _ in range(1000)] + [target])

result = finiteRange(target,arr,0,1)
print(result)
```